# kivy: after remove_widget it disappears from the screen but stays in ids

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am making an arkanoid game and having a problem: after collision I am using `remove_widget` method to remove a widget from layout. So it disappears from the screen but it is still in there, it is available by `ids` and if the ball enters that point again it still collides with a widget.

Here is some code:

*gemsgrid.kv*

```
<Brick@Widget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<GemsGrid@FloatLayout>:
    size_hint: None, None
    Brick:
        pos: 300, 100
        id: 1
    Brick:
        pos: 300,200
        id: 2
```

*main.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


Builder.load_file('paddle.kv')
Builder.load_file('ball.kv')
Builder.load_file('gemsgrid.kv')


class Game(RelativeLayout):
    lives = NumericProperty(5)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.game_started = False

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.y < self.height / 3:
            self.ids.paddle_widget.center_x = touch.x
            if not self.game_started:
                self.ids.ball_widget.serve_ball()
                self.game_started = True

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.game_started:
            self.ids.ball_widget.move()
            self.ids.paddle_widget.bounce_ball(self.ids.ball_widget)
            for id, gem in self.gemsgrid.ids.iteritems():
                if self.ids.ball_widget.collide_widget(gem):
                    self.gemsgrid.remove_widget(gem)
                    self.right_left_collissioned(self.ids.ball_widget, gem)
                    self.top_bottom_collissioned(self.ids.ball_widget, gem)

        # bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ids.ball_widget.top > self.height):
            self.ids.ball_widget.velocity_y *= -1

        # bounce off left and right
        if (self.ids.ball_widget.x < 0) or (self.ids.ball_widget.right > self.width):
            self.ids.ball_widget.velocity_x *= -1

        # subtract one life if hit the bottom but not the paddle
        if (self.ids.ball_widget.y < self.y):
            self.lives -= 1
            self.ids.ball_widget.reset()
            self.game_started = False

    def right_left_collissioned(self, ball, gem):
        if ball.y > gem.y and ball.y < (gem.y + gem.height):
            ball.velocity_x *= -1

    def top_bottom_collissioned(self, ball, gem):
            if ball.x > gem.x and ball.x < gem.x + gem.width:
                ball.velocity_y *= -1


class MainApp(App):
    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1/60)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ids` is generated when the `.kv` has been parsed.
So it will stay that way.

Use `self.children` instead to check if it is still there.

Comment: That is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ids dict is static and is not intended to update like this (although I don't see why it couldn't be changed if people really want the feature). It sounds like it just isn't a good fit for your problem, I would manage the object references manually.